# Azure Key Vault - How to update the secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

In Azure Portal > Key vaults > Secrets, I have secrets with json values (I did not create it). Something like:

> ...
>
> "SubscriptionId": "XXXXXXX",
>   "BaseAuthUri":      "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXX/oauth/authorize?client_id="&api-version=
>   ...

- I would like to add another url value to it. How can I edit the
  secrets with Azure portal?

  - How the value of api-version set?

Thanks

Answer (score 38):

You can only change secret attributes such as expiration date, activation date. You cannot change secret's value programatically or via Azure Portal. If you want to update your secret without creating a new vault (meaning the secret identifier still remains intact) you can create a new version of the existing secret.

[image]

If the secret value contains the variables to get authorization code, you don't need api version because the URI you call is the authorization endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge (and helping others). It's a well written response. Worked like charm for my case. +1