# Change password for Key Vault in Azure

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to change only the password in a Key Vault I created with PowerShell   and resides in Azure? I found this thread but unsure if this is the answer:

[Azure Key Vault - How to update the secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907912/azure-key-vault-how-to-update-the-secrets)

Want to  know for sure before I start fiddeling around. It would be nice to be able to change password and not removing the whole KeyVault. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can update the secret of the keyvault with `Update-AzureKeyVaultSecret`, do note that you need to have `Azure RM Powershell 6.8.1` . It's not available on older versions.

Refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/update-azurekeyvaultsecret?view=azurermps-6.8.1)

To check the version of AzureRM that is installed run this

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRm
```

Comment: stupid question: I have downloaded and installed Azure RM Powershell 6.8.1. But how do I access it? If I open start menu and open PowerShell, and then type $PSVersionTable I get PSversion 5. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: @CobraKaj AzureRm is a module inside PowerShell , to check the version of AzureRm run this `Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRm` and please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you

Comment: Thanks, Get-InstalledModule -Name AzureRm worked and I have 6.8.1
However, I see the input fields in the module but  I don't see how I can change the password with the module. The password is contained within the connectionString part